# Problems to show tables (with NiceTabular) using paracol package

Tags: paracol

I am doing a long table using `NiceTabular` and `paracol` packages for to show in three columns.
The long of the table not a problem because I do two diferent tables, each for column. The really problem is when after compile (at least three times) the tables are cutting on the page, ie not appear complete. I add that I need the page in landscape format.

Next the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[es]{pgf-PeriodicTable}
\usepackage{tikz}
      \usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,shadows,shapes,arrows,spy,positioning,snakes,matrix,animations,fadings,patterns}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
    
\newcommand{\met}{\emph{metal}}
\newcommand{\nmet}{\emph{no metal}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{paracol}{3}
    \columnratio{.3,.3,.3}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\rotatebox{-90}{
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
\scalebox{.5}
{\begin{NiceTabularX}{0.5\textwidth}{>{\tiny}l|>{\tiny}p{1cm}|>{\tiny}c|>{\centering\tiny}p{1cm}|>{\centering\tiny}p{1cm}|>{\tiny\centering}p{1cm}|>{\tiny}p{1cm}}
    \CodeBefore
    \rowlistcolors{3}{gray!15,gray!30}
    \Body
    \multicolumn{7}{c}{Características de los elementos}\\
    \toprule
    Nombre & Símb. & Z & Electrones de valencia & Período & Grupo & Clasif.\\
    \midrule
    Actinio & Ac & 89 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Aluminio & Al & 13 & 3 & & & \met\\
    Americio & Am & 95 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Antimonio & Sb & 51 & 5 & & & \nmet\\
    Argón & Ar & 18 & 8 & & & \nmet\\
    Arsénico & As & 33 & 5 & & & \nmet\\
    Astato & At & 85 & 7 & & & \nmet\\
    Azufre & S & 16 & 6 & & & \nmet\\
    \midrule
    Bario & Ba & 56 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Berilio & Be & 4 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Berkelio & Bk & 97 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Bismuto & Bi & 83 & 5 & & & \met\\
    Bohrio & Bh & 107 & --- & & & ---\\
    Boro & B & 5 & 3 & & & \nmet\\
    Bromo & Br & 35 & 7 & & & \nmet\\
    \midrule
    Cadmio & Cd & 48 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Calcio & Ca & 20 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Californio & Cf & 98 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Carbono & C & 6 & 4 & & & \nmet\\
    Cerio & Ce & 58 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Cesio & Cs & 55 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Cinc & Zn & 30 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Circonio & Zr & 40 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Cloro & Cl & 17 & 7 & & & \nmet\\
    Cobalto & Co & 27 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Cobre & Cu & 29 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Copernicio & Cn & 112 & --- && & ---\\
    Criptón & Kr & 36 & 8 & & & \nmet\\
    Cromo & Cr & 24 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Curio & Cm & 96 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Darmstadtium & Ds & 110 & --- && & ---\\
    Disprosio & Dy & 66 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Dubnium & Db & 105 & --- & & & ---\\
    \midrule
    Einstenio & Ei & 99 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Erbio & Er & 68 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Escandio & Sc & 21 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Estaño & Sn & 50 & 4 & & & \met\\
    Estroncio & Sr & 38 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Europio & Eu & 63 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Fermio & Fm & 100 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Flerovio & Fl & 114 & --- && & ---\\
    Flúor & F & 9 & 7 & & & \nmet\\
    Fósforo & P & 15 & 5 & & & \nmet\\
    Francio & Fr & 87 & 1 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Gadolinio & Gd & 64 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Galio & Ga & 31 & 3 & & & \met\\
    Germanio & Ge & 32 & 4 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Hafnio & Hf & 72 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Hasio & Hs & 108 & --- && & ---\\
    Helio & He & 2 & 2 & & & \nmet\\
    Hidrógeno & H & 1 & 1 & & & \nmet\\
    Hierro & Fe & 26 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Holmio & Ho & 67 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
}}
\end{leftcolumn}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\rotatebox{-90}
{
\scalebox{.5}{
\begin{NiceTabularX}{0.5\textwidth}{>{\tiny}l|>{\tiny}p{1cm}|>{\tiny}c|>{\centering\tiny}p{1cm}|>{\centering\tiny}p{1cm}|>{\tiny\centering}p{1cm}|>{\tiny}p{1cm}}
    \CodeBefore
    \rowlistcolors{2}{gray!15,gray!30}
    \Body
    Nombre & Símb. & Z & Electrones de valencia & Período & Grupo & Clasif.\\
    \midrule
    Indio & In & 49 & 3 & & & \met\\
    Iridio & Ir & 77 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Iterbio & Yb & 70 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Itrio & Y & 39 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Lantano & La & 57 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Lawrencium & Lw & 103 & --- && & ---\\
    Litio & Li & 3 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Livermorio & Lv & 116 & --- && & ---\\
    Lutecio & Lu & 71 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Magnesio & Mg & 12 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Manganeso & Mn & 25 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Meitnerio & Mt & 109 & --- && & ---\\
    Mendelevio & Md & 101 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Mercurio & Hg & 80 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Molibdeno & Mo & 42 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Moscovio & Mc & 115 & --- && & ---\\
    \midrule
    Neodimio & Nd & 60 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Neón & Ne & 10 & 8 & & & \nmet\\
    Neptunio & Np & 93 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Nihonio & Nh & 113 & --- && & ---\\
    Niobio & Nb & 41 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Níquel & Ni & 28 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Nitrógeno & N & 7 & 5 & & & \nmet\\
    Nobelio & No & 102 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Oganesón & Og & 118 & --- & & & ---\\
    Oro & Au & 79 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Osmio & Os & 76 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Oxígeno & O & 8 & 6 & & & \nmet\\
    \midrule
    Paladio & Pd & 46 & 10 & & & \met\\
    Plata & Ag & 47 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Platino & Pt & 78 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Plomo & Pb & 82 & 4 & & & \met\\
    Plutonio & Pu & 94 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Polonio & Po & 84 & 6 & & & \nmet\\
    Potasio & K & 19 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Praseodimio & Pr & 59 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Prometio & Pm & 61 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Protactinio & Pa & 91 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Radio & Ra & 88 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Radón & Rn & 86 & 8 & & & \nmet\\
    Renio & Re & 75 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Rodio & Rh & 45 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Roentgenio & Rg & 111 & --- && & ---\\
    Rubidio & Rb & 37 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Rutenio & Ru & 44 & & & & \met\\
    Rutherfordio & Rf & 104 & --- & & & ---\\
    \midrule
    Samario & Sm & 62 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Seaborgio & Sg & 106 & --- && & ---\\
    Selenio & Se & 34 & 6 & & & \nmet\\
    Silicio & Si & 14 & 4 & & & \nmet\\
    Sodio & Na & 11 & 1 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Talio & Tl & 81 & 3 & & & \met\\
    Tantalio & Ta & 73 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Tecnecio & Tc & 43 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Telurio & Te & 52 & 6 & & & \nmet\\
    Teneso & Ts & 117 & --- && & ---\\
    Terbio & Tb & 65 & 1 & & & \met\\
    Titanio & Ti & 22 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Torio & Th & 90 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Tulio & Tm & 69 & 2 & & & \met\\
    Tungsteno & W & 74 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Uranio & U & 92 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Vanadio & V & 23 & 2 & & & \met\\
    \midrule
    Xenón & Xe & 54 & 8 & & & \nmet\\
    \midrule
    Yodo & I & 53 & 7 & & & \nmet\\
\end{NiceTabularX}}
}
\end{rightcolumn}

\switchcolumn

\begin{rightcolumn}
    \rotatebox{-90}{y otra}
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

and the pdf's page after compile:

[image]

somebody know how show the complete table?

Thanks a lot!
Darío